TypeError: server.listeners is not a function at Server.attach (/var/task/api/node_modules/engine.io/build/server.js:642:34) at attach
Iam getting this error in vercel deployement
And it's working fine in local when i tried on local host
I have refered to the previous issues but could find any help
I can provide frontend code if needed
TypeError: server.listeners is not a function
at Server.attach (/var/task/api/node_modules/engine.io/build/server.js:642:34)
at attach (/var/task/api/node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js:53:12)
at Server.initEngine (/var/task/api/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js:293:43)

⛁ MongoDb is connected ✅

Code
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import blogRoutes from "./routes/blog.route.js";
import resumeRoutes from "./routes/resume.route.js";
import chatRoutes from "./routes/chat.route.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import path from "path";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import http from "http";
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("⛁ MongoDb is connected ✅");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/blog", blogRoutes);
app.use("/api/resume", resumeRoutes);
app.use("/api/chats", chatRoutes);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('a user disconnected');
  });
});

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const distDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist');
app.use(express.static(distDirectory));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(distDirectory, 'index.html'));
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";
  console.error(message);
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    statusCode,
    message,
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(` Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000} `);
});

export default io;


This is my code Please help me to resolve tis error
I have completed this app and working fine in localhost
giving error on vercel deployment

Which version of socket.io your using?

The latest version (4.7.5)
